# ejecutar script en segundo plano python

Tags: python, script, flask

buen día.
actualmente estoy trabajando en un proyecto móvil.
tengo este script

```
def newToken(refsh):

    newToken = Auth.refresh(refsh)    
    print('New token en 50min...')
    time.sleep(3000)
    return newToken['idToken']
```

y lo llamo de esta forma

```
while True:
    TokenNew = Helper.newToken(refsh)
    print('TokenNew: '+str(TokenNew))
tk = TokenNew
return jsonify({'newtoken': tk})
```

Lo que hace el script: le mando el token refresh el refrescar el token cada 50 min y asi mi app no le cierre la session al usuario.
Quiero que se ejecute en segundo plano ya que cuando lo llamo se queda en un bucle que si genera el token pero no lo hace return.

Si alguien me puede ayudar o si existe una forma mejor para hacerlo lo agradeceria mucho. 
Feliz dia.

Comment: No será mas facil extender el tiempo de vida del token? Utilizar while True y time.sleep son muy malas practicas, en especial en aplicaciones graficas / web.

Answer (score 0):

Si se trata de ejecutar una tarea periodicamente lo mejor es hacer uso de las librerias timer y threading.  [En stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600161/executing-periodic-actions-in-python) puedes encontrar una pregunta relacionada con el tema. 
Adaptando, a tu caso, el ejemplo aportado en dicha pregunta podría quedarte un código tal que así:

```
import time, threading
def newToken(refsh):
    newToken = Auth.refresh(refsh)    
    print('New token en 50min...')
    #Aquí ejecutar las acciones necesarias 
    threading.Timer(3000, newToken,[refsh]).start()
```

De esta manera se evita bloquear el hilo principal (segundo plano), a la vez que se simplifica el código.